# Retrieving value from input in EJS with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ejs

Here is my EJS code:

```html
<form action="/" method="POST">
            <% items.forEach((item)=>{ %>
            <div class="item">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%=item._id%>" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <p><%= item.name %></p>
            </div>
            <% }) %>

</form>
```

And here is the app.js:

```
app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body.checkbox);
})
```

My questions are:

1) Why does it only log the value of the selected checkbox (assumed that there are 3 items) instead of 3 values, is it because of the post method only post the checkbox's value that has the property `checked` == true?

2) If I add another checkbox like below, why does it return *undefined* if I try to `console.log(req.body.item_id)`?

```html
<form action="/" method="POST">
            <% items.forEach((item)=>{ %>
            <div class="item">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%=item._id%>" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <p><%= item.name %></p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="item_id" value="<%=item._id%>">
            </div>
            <% }) %>

</form>
```

3) I've tried to do the same thing above but this time it is using `input` type of `text`. Why does the `console.log(req.body.item_id)` show 3 values instead of 1 (which corresponds with the selected checkbox like in question 1)?

```html
<form action="/" method="POST">
            <% items.forEach((item)=>{ %>
            <div class="item">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%=item._id%>" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <p><%= item.name %></p>
                <input name="item_id" value="<%=item._id%>">
            </div>
            <% }) %>
</form>
```

**All response are appreciated. Thank you!**

Comment: 1. Because you are logging `checkbox` value which is the name of that input field. Try `console.log(req.body)` to see all the values in the reqBody
And also if you have two checkboxes with same name and try to log like `console.log(req.body.<your check box name here>)` will log the check box which is checked if you check both array of those checkbox values will be logged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. That is the default behaviour of the checkbox, it only gets
   passed as data if its checked, if it doesn't get passed, we can
   assume it wasn't checked

   - However if you still want the checkbox in data even if it was not checked, one hack would be

     - Create a hidden element with same name as your checkbox & set value as 'off'
     - Before submit, if the checkbox is checked, disable the hidden input element
     - this will give your  checkbox value 'on' when checked & 'off' when its not
2. As mentioned above, it will only added to formdata if its
   checked, when its not checked, the element is not added to formdata
   at all, so you will get undefined if its not checked
3. Again this is default behaviour of input types, the reason it
   does not do same for checkbox is because, maybe you are only
   selecting 1 checkbox with same name before submit, if you do select
   multiple checkbox with same name in checkboxes, you'll get same
   result for checkboxes too, but due to the reason mentioned in first
   answer, it only get's us the element selected which is 1 in your
   case